# Gcloud deploy - push stuck

Tags: dart, gcloud

I want to deploy sample application as described here:

https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/client-server/

however it gets stuck almost at the end of the pushing

> Pushing: [=================================================> ] 93.18 MB/93.34 MB

Is it stucked or does it work on background?
I'm also not sure if the progress bar is really showing the upload because the progress is much faster than it could be through my internet connection.

Comment: As far as I remember you have just to be patient. It can a long time until the Docker image is uploaded.

Comment: Ensure that you exclude all files otherwise `gcloud deploy` deploys all source files twice see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176322